# New Econ.SE discord server

Tags: discussion

In a recent post about getting mods attention off site other than flags and I created a discord server.

The permanant link is: https://discord.gg/Q8TNQbf

Feel free to tag me to let me know you're in.

Comment: Heads up from me, the new link should not expire now.

Comment: this is the permanent link

Comment: edit the post stating so wink wink